# How do I display .ics data in calendar format, in a ruby on rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, frontend, icalendar

I am pulling .ics files from a third party api, and I would like to display the ics data in a calendar view. Is there a plugin out there that would allow me to import an array of ics files(a single ics file would do for now), for easy front end integration?

I'm presently using iCalendar to parse the ics files.

Any ideas or suggestions are hugely appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should try [iCalendar](https://github.com/sdague/icalendar), it parses ics files.

Edit: for display you can use [Full Calendar](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails)

From iCalendar you can create an `Event` model so you can store all the relevant attributes, and then use the power of Rails via an events index view as below.

```
# in events controller
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end
end

# in events index view
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: "<%= @events.to_json %>"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: "I'm presently using ical to parse the ics files."

Comment: My question is about displaying the parsed ics data in a view

Comment: Sorry added the Full Calendar gem, used it on a couple of project, quite good

Comment: Any tips on getting the parsed data into full calendar? In one post, someone converted the ics data to json - and passed the json to full calendar...what was your process?

Comment: I've created an `Event` model so I can store whichever attributes I want from the ics, and then use the power of Rails via an `EventController` and a bit of JavaScript, cf the updated comment.

Comment: Sure thing, don't forget to tick accepted answer if that fully answers you  :)

Comment: Is it bad form to wait and see if someone else has another suggestion? I was looking at 'big calendar' which is a react calendar inspired by 'full calendar' I especially like the agenda view in 'big calendar'. 'full calendar' doesn't seem to have a view similar to the agenda view of 'big calendar'. Check this out: http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html

Comment: Sure, you can wait no worries. Ultimately you can create your own calendar in Rails itself, with a calendar model and regular views, from there you can customize everything really.